# Unknown filesystem with GRUB rescue caption cannot boot

Tags: ubuntu, grub, supergrubdisk

I just recently partitioned my hard drive and I got this error when booting Ubuntu on that drive.

```
unknown filesystem
```

followed by the GRUB rescue terminal.

I did some research and tried to download super grub disk but I cant seem to fix it with that. I have two hard disks. One with Windows Vista on it and the other with Ubuntu which is the one I partitioned.

There was 100 GB reserved for all the Ubuntu partitions that I needed and the rest was split into two partitions, one for backup folders for my Windows machine and the other for music production which is the one that I created. The space used to created that was shrunk from my backup partition so I didn't mess with any of the Ubuntu partitions. As of now there are a total of 5 partitions.

I also downloaded Rescatux which is another Super GRUB Disk for GRUB 2 not knowing which grub I had. It still didn't work. In Super Grub Disk I tried to swap the hard disk because that was what was said to do in order to fix the grub, that didn't work it said it was unsuccessful. I even tried to unplug the Windows hard disk and run Super GRUB Disk and that wasn't successful either.

Is there another way I can fix this? Please any help would be greatly appreciated. I would like to have a nice step by step response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following [the instructions on the Ubuntu website to reinstall GRUB2 from an Ubuntu Live CD or USB drive](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202).